# how to exclude an object from the list field of a java class using jackson filter

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to generate a json object in java using jackson and I need to filter some of the objects from one of the fields in json. I have a following class which I am trying to convert into json

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties( {"done", "parent" })
public class Node {
    private String start;
    private String end;
    private int done;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;

    public Node (String start, String end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.done=0;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Here the condition on filtering is if `done == 1 then do not include that node in the list of children`. For example if I have following data structure

```
obj1: start="1", end="1", done=0, parent=null, children=[obj2, obj3] 
obj2: start="2", end="2", done=1, parent=obj1, children=[] 
obj3: start="3", end="3", done=0, parent=obj1, children=[]
```

So the final json should look like

```
{start:"1", end:"1", children:[{start:"3", end:"3", children:[]}]}
```

and not

```
{start:"1", end:"1", children:[{start:"2", end:"2", children:[]}, {start:"3", end:"3", children:[]}]}
```

I know how basic filtering works in jackson, so I was doing the following

```
public void formJson(Node node) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    PropertyFilter filter = new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
        @Override
        public void serializeAsField
                (Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
                throws Exception {
            if (include(writer)) {
                int done = ((Node) pojo).getDone();
                if (done == 1) {
                    writer.serializeAsOmittedField(null, jgen, provider);
                }
                else{
                    writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter", filter);
    try {
        String jsonInString = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(node);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Which I understand that the above approach would be good if I want to exclude the field completely but here am not necessarily excluding any field but just updating that field based on a condition. So this does not achieve what I want to do, it always include `obj2` in the final json if I pass `obj1` to `formJson` method. I thought internally jackson would have to process each node in children list and it would apply the filtering logic to each node in the list and if it is doing so it should exclude the node from the children that has `done` field as 1. Maybe I am missing something here, any help on this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve the problem I finally decided to not use the jackson at all and just generate a json using a string builder.

This is how I am forming the json

```
private void formJson(Node node, StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.append("{\"start\": \"");
        sb.append(node.getStart());
        sb.append("\", \"end\": ");
        sb.append(node.getEnd());

        sb.append(", \"children\": [");
        for (Node n: node.getChildrens()){
            if(n.getDone()==1){
                continue;
            }
            formJson(n, sb);
            sb.append(",");
        }
        if (sb.charAt(sb.length()-1)==','){
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
        }
        sb.append("]");
        sb.append("}");
    }
```